# How to perform boolean operations with gcc vectors like the normal value?

Tags: gcc, boolean, simd

For a normal value, `1` is used to represent true while `0` for false:

```
float a = 1.0f;
float b = 2.0f;
float c = (a > b);  // this will be 0.0f
```

But for a vector, `1111...111`(32 binary 1s) is used to represent true while `0` for false. To floats, 32 binary 1s is -nan (Not a Number with minus sign):

```
typedef float v4 __attribute__((vector_size(sizeof(float)*4)));
v4 a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
v4 b = {0 ,1, 4, 5};
v4 c = (a > b); // this becomes { -nan, -nan, 0.0f, 0.0f }
```

**My question is:**
Is it possible to "transform" c into `{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }` in a "vectorized" way?

In fact, I want to do "clamp" (`max(min(value, maximum), minimal)`) for pixel's RGBs. If the above is not achievable, any other good method for doing clamp in a vectorized way?

PS: I prefer ***non***-intrinsics ways.

Comment: TBH, code written with SSE intrinsics is *more* portable than relying on GCC extensions...

Comment: My lib now is already only compatible with gcc. So don't consider the portability.